# jQuery, add css rule to specific element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I want after click on `button` my div with class `text-internal`(specific one - I I have more than one div with class `text-internal`) obtain `max-height`. As I said only specific div should obtain `max-height` - only this one, which is in container, which was clicked, others, which is not clicked not obtain `max-height`
I don't know if I explain it correctly and clear.

```
 <div class="single-offer-text">
        <div class="text-internal">
            <?php echo $params->get('mytextarea'); ?>
        </div>
        <button class="read-more">Read more</button>
    </div>
```

JQUERY

```
jQuery('.read-more-hide').click(function() {
    jQuery('.text-internal').css('maxHeight', '150px');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any number of traversal methods to isolate specific instance.

[`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) is a simple one that fits your scenario

```
jQuery('.read-more-hide').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).prev('.text-internal').css('maxHeight', '150px');
});
```

Or if relationship is not so simple you can traverse up to a common parent using `closest()` and then `find()` within that parent

```
jQuery('.read-more-hide').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).closest('.single-offer-text').find('.text-internal').css('maxHeight', '150px');
});
```

Comment: `jQuery.prev`? Is that new or did you mean `jQuery(this).prev`?